# Intellij doesn't wrapping field annotations

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij IDEA `2021.3.3`.

I want to set new line after each field annotations, but it doesn't work in some cases.

My `field annotations` settings are `wrap always` and unchecked `Do not wrap after single annotation`.

When I set field `final` or add access modifier(like `private`), reformat works as I expected.

Here's example.

```
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class Foo {

  // (1) Before reformat
  @Size(max = 10, message = "size message")
  @NotBlank(message = "notBlank message")
  String badField;

  // (1) After reformat
  @Size(max = 10, message = "size message") @NotBlank(message = "notBlank message") String badField;

  // (2) Before reformat
  @Size(max = 10, message = "size message")
  @NotBlank(message = "notBlank message")
  final String goodField;

  // (2) After reformat (Same as before)
  @Size(max = 10, message = "size message")
  @NotBlank(message = "notBlank message")
  final String goodField;
}
```

Are there any way to fix it?

Comment: See if it helps to press Ctrl+Alt+Shift+L (Cmd+Alt+Shift+L on macOS) and uncheck "Do not keep line breaks" in the formatter settings.